# Foundation 6 Toggled Title Bar Not Working On Only One Page Of Site

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

Unlike a lot of other posts on this topic, my title bar works just fine on every page, but one:

http://www.pcvsoftware.net/christlutheran/contact.html

On screens larger than small, I get the horizontal top menu. On my phone, I get the toggled title bar, with the hamburger menu icon that, when tapped, reveals the top menu bar as a vertical dropdown menu -- except for the page linked above. The code is identical on all pages. Could someone look at this and figure out what is wrong? I'd like to make the title bar sticky, but can't see making that effort until I can figure out why I have this problem. I thought it might be interference with the Google Maps API javascript, but commenting that out makes no difference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that I was initializing foundation twice, because Zurb had put $(document).foundation(); in app.js, and I was also including it at the bottom of the page. Since I had copied a skeleton for the page from a Foundation 5 page, it included the $(document).foundation(); at the end of the page before the `</body>` tag. Sorry for the confusion, although in my defense a migration guide would have been helpful.